# question from my exam: trivial solution only or more solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, $n \ge 3$. Assume $A^2 = 0$. 
Which  one is true and which one is false and explain:

1. The linear system $Ax = 0$ has only trivial solution.
2. The linear system $Ax = 0$ has more than only the trivial solution.
3. The linear system $(I - A)x$ has only trivial solution.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly.  Can you tell me why is it equivalent to A = 0 ? And about 3. I proved it by muliplying in I+A snd got I , is it a good explanation to show there's only trivial solution?

Comment: Sorry,  I meant A^2 = 0, very sorry

Comment: What's the correct answer then? Sorry. ..

Comment: @julien - since the OP didn't use LaTeX, I assumed that the * meant multiplication..

Comment: @nbubis And you were right. Good job.

Comment: It seems you were right. I edited before he changed his mind from $A^*A$ to $A^2$. Is there a way to cancel my edit?

Comment: @VedranŠego - fixed.

Comment: Yes, multiplying by $I+A$ is the way for 3.

Comment: If $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution, then for $x\ne0$, $Ax\ne0$. Then $A(Ax)=0$, a contradiction. So 1. is false. Item 2. is just the negation of item 1..

Comment: There's something that's confusing me about 3. If I look at (I- A) x = 0 and multiply it by A from the left side I get (A- A^2) x = 0 so it means Ax = 0 so more than trivial solution  but by the other way we got only trivial solution!  What's wrong?

Comment: The argument doesn't reverse. $BC=0$ does not imply $C=0$. (Note what you did,  and one more step, can be used to show 3. is true.)

Comment: Why can't I multiply A from left and deduce it? sorry i really dont understand, its not like BC = 0 -> C = 0 because I didn't assume it is invertible

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$0=\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$$
What does that tell you about the rank of $A$? is $A$ invertable?

Comment: There's something that's confusing me about 3. If I look at (I- A) x = 0 and multiply it by A from the left side I get (A- A^2) x = 0 so it means Ax = 0 so more than trivial solution but by the other way we got only trivial solution! What's wrong?

Comment: @user84636 - you can't multiply $x$ by $A$ on the right..

Comment: Okay but why does it matter that I can't?

Comment: @user84636 - then I didn't understand your previous comment..

Comment: What's the answer to 3 and why the way I wrote in the previous comment is not right?

Comment: @user84636 - I'm missing an equality in $3$. is the question $(I-A)x=0$?

Comment: yes , (I-A)x = 0